# Resizing Grid in Grid.Column via Storyboard?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a `Grid` defining two `ColumnDefinition`s:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="column0" Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="column1" Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="content0">
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="content1">
        <Button Content="Press me!" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Now I want to create a collapse animation using a `Storyboard`.
Therefor I created this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="myStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="content1"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
        From="??" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" EnableDependentAnimation="True" />
</Storyboard>
```

My problem is the `From` property.
If I enter a specific value like 100, everything works fine but I would like to do someting like `From={Binding ElementName=content1, Path=ActualWidth}` which didn't work.
I tried to create an IValueConverter but those don't work with `From`.
Also if I set `content1.Width = 100` in code-behind it works too.

Am I missing something or am I using the wrong animation type?

Edit: I tried to do something similar in a separate project for testing purposes.
I examined that it actually works but the return value of `{Binding ElementName=content1, Path=ActualWidth` seems to be always 0. The same happens when using`{Binding ElementName=content1, Path=Width`. Unfortunately I don't know why the value is always 0.

Edit2: Actually I'm not quite sure if my first edit is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in code rather than Xaml. As per your example do something like this

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveGrid();
    }

    private void MoveGrid()
    {
        var sb = new Storyboard();
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            To = 0,
            From = content1.ActualWidth,
            EnableDependentAnimation = true
        };
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Width");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, content1);
        sb.Children.Add(animation);

        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: That's it :) Such a mess for such a simple solution -.- Works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18379/WPF-Tutorial-Part-2-Writing-a-custom-animation-cla

In short `Width` is a `GridLength` so you need a custom `GridLengthAnimation` class.

Comment: Actually there was a typo in my question. I don't want to change the width of the ColumnDefinition but I want to change the width of a Grid and Grid.Width returns a double value.
I set the width of column1 to Auto because I thought it would be easier to animate the width of the Grid inside column1 so that the column resizes automatically but that seems not to work :(

Comment: No, the grid content1 will expand to fill the column of your main grid. I think it will be easier to animate the width of that column rather than content1.

Comment: In my case I think both ways are equally simple/difficult.
I had a look at the codeproject link but unfortunately the example can't be reproduced for store apps and I haven't figured out how to do it for winrt yet.